# Reload GWT server-side code from IntelliJ IDEA DevMode tool

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, dev-mode

I'm probably just missing something obvious, but the '*update*' button in IntelliJ IDEA's GWT DevMode tool seems to update only client-side code: any hints about forcing the embedded server to restart or reload classes (something like the '*Restart Server*' button in the '*Jetty*' tab available in the standalone GUI of DevMode)?

[IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.3; GWT 2.2; Mac OS X 10.6.7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the option to reload server-side classes isn't available in IDEA. We have an issue about that in our tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-49503. Feel free to vote/watch/comment it.